# Joomla Ja Slideshow Descriptions

Tags: joomla, slideshow

How do you display the descriptions in Ja Slideshow?
I found an example on the forums that goes like this:

```
[desc img="img.jpg" url="http://www.url.com"]
<h1> Title </h1>
<p>Bla</p>
[/desc]
```

However, even if i match url of desc item to url of img, it's not being displayed, and i'm not all together on how that would work for multiple images?

Answer (score 1):

```
Easy to do:

sl-1.jpg:caption=<h3>This is description for header 1</h3><br><p>Testing</hp>&url=http://www.yoururlhere.com

sl-2.jpg:caption=<h3>This is description for header 2</h3><br><p>Testing</hp>&url=http://www.yoururlhere.com

sl-3.jpg:caption=<h3>This is description for header 3</h3><br><p>Testing</hp>&url=http://www.yoururlhere.com

sl-4.jpg:caption=<h3>This is description for header 4</h3><br><p>Testing</hp>&url=http://www.yoururlhere.com
```